# jQuery Click Event Triggering without Clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a tricky problem with my code and hope to get some help on this. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>

function list(json) {
// list result
$('#pop-up').click(alert(json.length));
}

// declare map and options

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
var query = 'some query';
$.getJSON(query, list); 
});

</SCRIPT>
<A href='javascript:void(0)' id='pop-up'>Click Me</A>
```

As seen, the pop-up is supposed to return the length of json object when the pop-up link is clicked. However, I am getting the **pop-up without clicking** the link. Anyone knows where the problem lies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're using `.click()` rather than `.click(function() {})`. Replace the `$('#pop-up')` line with:

```
$('#pop-up').click(function() { alert(json.length) });
```

and get rid of the curly brace underneath that line.

Comment: Click the tick underneath the up/down voting arrows. Thanks!